# Update function in PHP using MVC architecture

Tags: php, sql, model-view-controller, phpmyadmin

I am doing a school project where I have to upload prescription image to SQL database using PHP in MVC architecture. I am giving controller code first model code second view code thirdly. Give me answer why image is not uploading to database.

**Controller**

```
public function upload_prescription_db()
{
    $this->CustomerModel = $this->model('Customer');
    if (isset($_POST["submit"]) && !empty($_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
        //retrieve file title
        $message = $_POST["message"];

        //upload directory path
        $uploads_dir = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\careU_project\public\img\prescription';

        $pname = basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
        $target_file = $uploads_dir . $filename;

        //file name with a random number so that similar dont get replaced
        $pname = rand(1000, 10000) . "-" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];

        //temporary file name to store file
        $tname = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

        $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $cid = $_SESSION['user_ID'];



        // get the file type
        $file_type = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

        // check if the file is an image
        if ($file_type != "jpg" && $file_type != "jpeg" && $file_type != "png") {
            echo "<script>
                        alert('Error: Only JPG, JPEG, and PNG files are allowed');
                        </script>";
            exit;
        }

        //TO move the uploaded file to specific location
        move_uploaded_file($tname, $uploads_dir . '/' . $pname);


        $r = $this->CustomerModel->upload_prescription_db($date, $cid, $pname, $message);
        $this->view('customers/home', $data);
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
public function upload_prescription_db($cid, $pname, $message, $date)
{
    $this->db->query("INSERT into customer_prescription VALUES(DEFAULT,:cid,:pname,:message,:date)");
    $this->db->bind(':date', $date);
    $this->db->bind(':cid', $cid);
    $this->db->bind(':pname', $pname);
    $this->db->bind(':message', $message);

    if ($this->db->execute()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<div class="form-div form-div-outer">
    <div class="form-div">
        <div class="img-prescription">
            <img class="img" src="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>/public/img/customer/prescription.png" alt="prescription">
            <h2>Upload Prescription</h2>
        </div>
        <form class="form" method="post" action="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>/Customers/upload_prescription_image" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label for="prescription" class="label-upload">Doctor's Prescription<span class="required">*</span> (Maxium upload size 5Mb)</label><br>
            <div class="div-prescription-upload">
                <input type="File" class="button-prescription-upload" name="file" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png">
            </div><br>

            <label for="number" class="label-upload">Your Message</label><br>
            <textarea class="prescription-textarea" rows="10" cols="70" type="text" id="message" name="message"></textarea><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" class="button-submit">

            <div></div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Give me reason and answer why my code is not running?

Comment: Please don't just dump a bunch of code and ask us to find an unspecified specific issue, other than just a vague "doesn't work" or "is not running". Those doesn't really tell us anything about the issue. Have you done any debugging to narrow the issue down to some _specific_ part of the code? What actually happens and what do you expect to happen in that case? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Do you receive an error?